# The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly. Xamarin.Android on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a real trouble with Xamarin for a couple of hours. I make changes in my code and try to run it as always. Then I got error that says `The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly`. I tried close my Mac, Visual Studio, rebuild, delete obj and bin folders, clean solution and nothing works for me. Does anyone have good solution for this problem? I am working on Mac with MacOS Mojave if that makes any difference. I looked for previous answers but nothing helped me.

**Full Error**

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB4018: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe.dll'
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0009a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:241 
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (System.String fullName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:186 
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (System.String fullName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:181 
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:176 
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] jars, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedResourceDirectories, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedAssetDirectories, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedEnvironments) [0x00283] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute () [0x000fc] in :0 
>     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00023] in /_/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:631 
>     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+d__26.MoveNext () [0x00212] in /_/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:787  (MSB4018) (EstiMOBILE.Droid)

**Part of Diagnostic Build Log**
   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):

> error MSB4018: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   assembly 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android
>   profile?
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018: File name: 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe.dll'
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference,
>   Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0009a] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:241
>
> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
> ```
>
> error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (System.String fullName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:186
>
> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
> ```
>
> error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (System.String fullName) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:181
>
> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
> ```
>
> error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly
>   (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:176
>
> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
> ```
>
> error MSB4018:   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract
>   (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] jars,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]
>   resolvedResourceDirectories,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedAssetDirectories,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedEnvironments)
>   [0x00283] in :0 
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute ()
>   [0x000fc] in :0 
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /_/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:631 
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+d__26.MoveNext
>   () [0x00212] in
>   /_/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:787
>   Done executing task "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" -- FAILED. Done
>   building target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" in project
>   "EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED. Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs"
>   in file
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
>   Done building target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in project
>   "EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj". Target "_SGenCheckForOutputs" skipped, due
>   to false condition; ('$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)'
>   == 'On' or ('@(WebReferenceUrl)'!='' and '$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'Auto')) was
>   evaluated as ('Off' == 'On' or (''!='' and 'Off' == 'Auto')). Target
>   "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in file
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
>   Task "ReadLinesFromFile"   Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
>   Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"   Done executing task
>   "ConvertToAbsolutePath".   Task "FindUnderPath"
>       Comparison path is "/Users/konraduciechowski/Projects/EstiMOBILE/Droid".   Done executing
>   task "FindUnderPath".   Task "FindUnderPath"
>       Comparison path is "bin/Debug/".   Done executing task "FindUnderPath".   Task "FindUnderPath"
>       Comparison path is "obj/Debug/".   Done executing task "FindUnderPath".   Task "RemoveDuplicates"   Done executing task
>   "RemoveDuplicates". Done building target
>   "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in project
>   "EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj". Target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in file
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
>   Task "RemoveDuplicates"   Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
>   Task "MakeDir"   Done executing task "MakeDir".   Task
>   "WriteLinesToFile"   Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile". Done
>   building target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in project
>   "EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj".
>
> Done building project "EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Project Evaluation Performance Summary:
>          60 ms  /Users/konraduciechowski/Projects/EstiMOBILE/iOS/EstiMOBILE.iOS.csproj
>   1 calls
>
> Project Performance Summary:
>         380 ms  /Users/konraduciechowski/Projects/EstiMOBILE/iOS/EstiMOBILE.iOS.csproj
>   4 calls
>         862 ms  /Users/konraduciechowski/Projects/EstiMOBILE/Droid/EstiMOBILE.Droid.csproj
>   1 calls
>
> Target Performance Summary:
>           0 ms  Codesign                                   1 calls
>           0 ms  ResGen                                     1 calls
>           0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
>           0 ms  AfterResGen                                1 calls
>           0 ms  PrepareResources                           1 calls
>           0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 1 calls
>           0 ms  PrepareResourceNames                       1 calls
>           0 ms  GenerateManifests                          1 calls
>           0 ms  AfterCodesign                              1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileImageAssets                        1 calls
>           0 ms  BeforeCodesign                             1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileCoreMLModels                       1 calls
>           0 ms  _CreateAppBundle                           1 calls
>           0 ms  PrepareForRun                              1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileSceneKitAssets                     1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileColladaAssets                      1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileInterfaceDefinitions               1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileTextureAtlases                     1 calls
>           0 ms  Compile                                    1 calls
>           0 ms  BeforeCompile                              1 calls
>           0 ms  BeforeResGen                               1 calls
>           0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                  1 calls
>           0 ms  CoreCodesign                               1 calls
>           0 ms  _OptimizePngImages                         1 calls
>           0 ms  _OptimizePropertyLists                     1 calls
>           0 ms  AfterCompile                               1 calls
>           0 ms  _OptimizeLocalizationFiles                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory          1 calls
>           0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames          1 calls
>           0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
>           0 ms  _ResolveMonoAndroidFramework               1 calls
>           0 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          2 calls
>           0 ms  BeforeBuild                                2 calls
>           0 ms  ResolveNativeReferences                    2 calls
>           0 ms  _SetupDesignTimeBuildForBuild              1 calls
>           0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    2 calls
>           0 ms  _SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense       1 calls
>           0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     2 calls
>           0 ms  Build                                      1 calls
>           0 ms  _RoslynPublicSignHack                      1 calls
>           0 ms  PrepareProjectReferences                   2 calls
>           0 ms  GetTargetPath                              2 calls
>           0 ms  _SplitWatchAppReferencesByExistent         1 calls
>           0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          2 calls
>           0 ms  _SplitAppExtensionReferencesByExistent     1 calls
>           0 ms  _ValidateLinkMode                          1 calls
>           0 ms  _PrepareResourceRules                      1 calls
>           0 ms  XamlG                                      2 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckForContent                           1 calls
>           0 ms  _SeparateWatchAppReferences                1 calls
>           0 ms  CssG                                       2 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckTargetFramework                      1 calls
>           0 ms  _CopyWatchOS2AppsToBundle                  1 calls
>           0 ms  _ValidateMSBuild                           2 calls
>           0 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        1 calls
>           0 ms  _FindCSSFiles                              1 calls
>           0 ms  GetNativeManifest                          1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreCompileTextureAtlases                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _FindXamlGFiles                            1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles             1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreOptimizePropertyLists                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _SetupInstantRun                           1 calls
>           0 ms  _SetupApplicationJavaClass                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _SetupDesignTimeBuildForCompile            1 calls
>           0 ms  _ValidateXFTasks                           2 calls
>           0 ms  _ResolveAppExtensionReferences             1 calls
>           0 ms  _GetCompileToNativeInputs                  1 calls
>           0 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        2 calls
>           0 ms  _ResolveWatchAppReferences                 1 calls
>           0 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       2 calls
>           0 ms  _GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _GenerateBundleName                        1 calls
>           0 ms  _ReadAppExtensionDebugSymbolProperties     1 calls
>           0 ms  _ReadAppExtensionCodesignProperties        1 calls
>           0 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     1 calls
>           0 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs           1 calls
>           0 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        1 calls
>           0 ms  _ReadCoreCompileTextureAtlases             1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreCompileColladaAssets                  1 calls
>           0 ms  _ReadCoreCompileSceneKitAssets             1 calls
>           0 ms  _CleanUploaded                             1 calls
>           0 ms  _SeparateAppExtensionReferences            2 calls
>           0 ms  _BeforeCompileCoreMLModels                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases               3 calls
>           0 ms  _CreatePropertiesCache                     1 calls
>           0 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets           3 calls
>           0 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        1 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckInstantRunCondition                  1 calls
>           0 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets              1 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckForDeletedResourceFile               1 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    2 calls
>           0 ms  CoreResGen                                 1 calls
>           0 ms  _CheckProjectItems                         1 calls
>           0 ms  _CreatePkgInfo                             1 calls
>           0 ms  _DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration           1 calls
>           0 ms  _CollectFrameworks                         1 calls
>           0 ms  _CompileAppManifest                        1 calls
>           0 ms  _CoreCompileCoreMLModels                   1 calls
>           0 ms  GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker     2 calls
>           0 ms  _CreateAssetPackManifest                   1 calls
>           1 ms  _ReadPropertiesCache                       1 calls
>           1 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    1 calls
>           1 ms  _CollectLocalizationFiles                  1 calls
>           1 ms  _CoreCompileImageAssets                    1 calls
>           1 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    1 calls
>           1 ms  XamlC                                      1 calls
>           1 ms  _CollectColladaAssets                      1 calls
>           1 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              1 calls
>           1 ms  _CollectPropertyLists                      1 calls
>           1 ms  _CreateDebugConfiguration                  1 calls
>           1 ms  _DetectAppManifest                         1 calls
>           1 ms  _ParseExtraMtouchArgs                      1 calls
>           1 ms  _CopyAppExtensionsToBundle                 1 calls
>           1 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     2 calls
>           1 ms  _ComputeTargetArchitectures                1 calls
>           1 ms  ResolveReferences                          1 calls
>           1 ms  _CollectPngImages                          1 calls
>           1 ms  _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions     1 calls
>           1 ms  _CompileToNative                           1 calls
>           1 ms  _DetectSigningIdentity                     1 calls
>           1 ms  _ReadCompileCoreMLModels                   1 calls
>           1 ms  _ReadCompileImageAssets                    1 calls
>           1 ms  _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions           1 calls
>           1 ms  _CleanRecordFileWrites                     1 calls
>           1 ms  _CreateDebugSettings                       1 calls
>           1 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          1 calls
>           1 ms  _ReadCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions       1 calls
>           1 ms  _ValidateAppBundle                         1 calls
>           1 ms  _GetNativeExecutableName                   1 calls
>           1 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 1 calls
>           1 ms  PrepareForBuild                            2 calls
>           2 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 2 calls
>           2 ms  _GetPrimaryCpuAbi                          1 calls
>           2 ms  _ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths          1 calls
>           3 ms  _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties          1 calls
>           3 ms  AssignLinkMetadata                         2 calls
>           3 ms  _CoreOptimizePngImages                     1 calls
>           4 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   2 calls
>           4 ms  _CollectBundleResources                    1 calls
>           6 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  2 calls
>           6 ms  _CopyResourcesToBundle                     1 calls
>           7 ms  IncrementalClean                           1 calls
>           8 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache            1 calls
>           8 ms  CoreCompile                                1 calls
>           9 ms  _AfterCoreOptimizePngImages                1 calls
>          11 ms  _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks                    1 calls
>          11 ms  _CodesignNativeLibraries                   1 calls
>          12 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         2 calls
>          14 ms  _ComputeAndroidResourcePaths               1 calls
>          16 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                  1 calls
>          19 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   2 calls
>          20 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades          1 calls
>          26 ms  _UnpackLibraryResources                    1 calls
>          43 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences       1 calls
>          48 ms  _ResolveLibraryProjectImports              1 calls
>          57 ms  _DetectSdkLocations                        1 calls
>          73 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties   2 calls
>         211 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  2 calls
>         527 ms  _SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion           1 calls
>
> Task Performance Summary:
>           0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           1 calls
>           0 ms  AssignCulture                              1 calls
>           0 ms  ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput             1 calls
>           0 ms  GetAppSettingsDirectory                    1 calls
>           0 ms  DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration            1 calls
>           0 ms  CreatePkgInfo                              1 calls
>           0 ms  CheckProjectItems                          1 calls
>           0 ms  GetAndroidDefineConstants                  1 calls
>           0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          2 calls
>           0 ms  CollectFrameworks                          1 calls
>           0 ms  ParseExtraMtouchArgs                       1 calls
>           0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  3 calls
>           0 ms  Delete                                     2 calls
>           0 ms  CreateAssetPackManifest                    1 calls
>           0 ms  CreateDebugConfiguration                   1 calls
>           0 ms  FindItemWithLogicalName                    1 calls
>           0 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      2 calls
>           0 ms  RemoveDir                                  1 calls
>           0 ms  Touch                                      1 calls
>           0 ms  GetAndroidPackageName                      1 calls
>           1 ms  GetJavaPlatformJar                         1 calls
>           1 ms  GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask     1 calls
>           1 ms  Hash                                       1 calls
>           1 ms  DetectSigningIdentity                      1 calls
>           1 ms  AssignTargetPath                           5 calls
>           1 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           2 calls
>           1 ms  CreateDebugSettings                        1 calls
>           1 ms  GetNativeExecutableName                    1 calls
>           1 ms  ValidateAppBundleTask                      1 calls
>           1 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 2 calls
>           1 ms  MakeDir                                    4 calls
>           1 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          3 calls
>           1 ms  GetPrimaryCpuAbi                           1 calls
>           2 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           4 calls
>           2 ms  ReadItemsFromFile                          5 calls
>           2 ms  ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths           1 calls
>           3 ms  Message                                   17 calls
>           4 ms  CollectBundleResources                     2 calls
>           6 ms  CreateProperty                            39 calls
>           7 ms  FindUnderPath                              8 calls
>           7 ms  CreateItem                                40 calls
>          11 ms  CodesignNativeLibraries                    1 calls
>          13 ms  AndroidComputeResPaths                     1 calls
>          16 ms  Copy                                       3 calls
>          26 ms  UnpackLibraryResources                     1 calls
>          48 ms  ResolveLibraryProjectImports               1 calls
>          57 ms  DetectSdkLocations                         1 calls
>          88 ms  MSBuild                                    4 calls
>         208 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   2 calls
>         527 ms  ResolveSdks                                1 calls
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2126,5):
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "mscorlib" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are
>   listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2126,5):
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "System" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are
>   listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2126,5):
>   warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
>   property to true in the project file. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   assembly 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android
>   profile?
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018: File name: 'EstiMOBILE.iOS.exe.dll'
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference,
>   Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0009a] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:241
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (System.String fullName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:186
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
>   (System.String fullName) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:181
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly
>   (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/6090/86d33f45/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:176
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract
>   (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] jars,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]
>   resolvedResourceDirectories,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedAssetDirectories,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] resolvedEnvironments)
>   [0x00283] in :0 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute ()
>   [0x000fc] in :0 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /_/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:631 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1273,2):
>   error MSB4018:   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+d__26.MoveNext
>   () [0x00212] in
>   /_/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:787 
>       3 Warning(s)
>       1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.61
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------
>
> Build: 1 error, 3 warnings

Comment: Could you please share a [Diagnostic Build Log](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs) about it?

Comment: You could refer to: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/the-resolvelibraryprojectimports-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I updated Post

Answer (score 1):

I found mistake by myself. I Tried everything that was posted in comment and nothing worked for me. I tried reinstall visual studio and this also doesn't work. So I looked at References Directory at Visual Studio and found out that in Android Solution exists reference to iOS Solution that isn't part of that Package. So I removed it update all packages and everything works!